# Mercurial push error from remote repository

Tags: mercurial

I have a server for mercurial repository with 2 drives:

- Drive C: - 50 Gb
- Drive E: - 1 Tb

As a web server for this repository I'm using internal web server that's launched via `hg serve` command. SSL disabled.

Mercurial version: 2.3.1.

Config file:

```
[web]
push_ssl = False
allow_push = *
port = 8080
```

My repository is placed on the drive E that have about 800 Gb of free space. Drive C usually running out of space and when this happens, I can't push anything to this repository because of error "HTTP Error 500: Error". If I free some space on drive C and restart web server, everything is ok.

Why is it matters how much space is available on drive C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, some temporary files are being created in the TMP directory.  Check that environment variable.  It is usually referencing the C: drive.